# Making auto detect COM-Port and WriteLine at a same time

Tags: c#, c++, winforms, windows, arduino-uno

Hello I just make Windows From Application, and I also doing Arduino project,
I want to make auto detect COM-Port and WriteLine at a same time, Here Is my codes...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;


namespace ForTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            foreach (string port in ports)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(port);
            }
            /// read button
            string t;
            t = comboBox1.Text.ToString();
            sErial(t);
        }

        SerialPort sp;
        void sErial(string Port_name)
        {
            sp = new SerialPort(Port_name, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            sp.Open();
            try
            {
                sp.WriteLine("G"); //send 1 to Arduino
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }


        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }



    }
}
```

Please help me.. I can not understand any thing now... I am fully BLIND... right now..... Inside Arduino my LED is not turning ON..

Comment: Bisect your problems. First of all, test arduino with terminal emulator. Ensure that it works. Then forget about auto-detecting COM ports and hardcode a proper one. Make it work with that. I do not advise to make auto-detection of COM ports because sending random data in random ports is not safe.

Comment: yes. arduino write line is. ok. but I need this like. COM3 and WRITELINE("G")

Comment: I am try to make an apps, that only do 2 thing, 1st: Find port and connect and open and 2ND: WRITELINE("G") that's it.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put SerialPort.Open() in try-catch block and call the SerialPort.Close() method after sending data:

```
  void Serial(string port)
  {
      SerialPort sp = new SerialPort(port, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
      try
      {
           sp.Open();
           try
           {
               sp.WriteLine("G"); // Send 1 to Arduino
               sp.Close();
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
           }
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message); 
       }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is working codes....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;


namespace ForTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            foreach (string port in ports)
            {
                SerialPort sp = new SerialPort(port, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
                try
                {
                    sp.Open();
                    try
                    {
                        sp.WriteLine("B"); // Send 1 to Arduino
                        sp.Close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ek)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ek.Message);
                }
            }


        } 

    }
}
```

Thank you...............